# LabVIEW 2017 does not open *.vi-File from LabVIEW 2016

Tags: labview

On my Windows 10 PC LabVIEW 2017 is installed. A file I created in LabVIEW 2016 at my Uni will not be opened. When I doubleklick, LabVIEW starts normally, but only as if I had opened it without any file. If I start LabVIEW normally and try to open the file out of the program, nothing will happen, not even an error will occur. Why is this?

Note: Right now I am using LabVIEW 2017 in Evaluation-Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason... The file was saved in a subfolder of a folder which name contained a right arrow (→) which is not supported by LabVIEW obviousely...

Comment: Really? I cannot replicate this as the cause of the issue. I named a folder with that exact character (copied from your post) and it worked just fine.

Comment: I copied the file to desktop and it worked... the right arrow was produced by [alt] +[2] +[6] (NUM pad)... I try it later today with another folder and let you know.. If I open the file, LabVIEW will also replace the right arrow by '?' in the directory. And I also was not able to save from LabVIEW in that folder

Comment: So, I reproduced your issue. Tried to send the resulting VIs to National Instruments for a bug report, but Windows wouldn't let me zip up the files because the directory name "includes characters that cannot be used in a compressed folder, such as →." Given that VIs have compressed sections, I bet that compression is done using the MS APIs. So I don't know that this can be fixed by NI. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Technically, I think the answer is that ASCII 26 is not a valid character for a Windows path or filename, per the following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including
>   Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set
>   (128–255), except for the following:
>
> The following reserved characters:
>
> < (less than)
>
> > (greater than)
>
> : (colon)
>
> " (double quote)
>
> / (forward slash)
>
> \ (backslash)
>
> | (vertical bar or pipe)
>
> ? (question mark)
>
> * (asterisk)
>
> Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
>
> **Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1
>   through 31**, except for alternate data streams where these characters
>   are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File
>   Streams.
>
> Any other character that the target file system does not allow.

(Emphasis mine.)